# Objects using Nurbs Curve disappear in game engine

Tags: game-engine, bezier-curves

I was trying to create train tracks using a NURBS curve and everything seems to work correctly during modeling. (I am working in Blender Game Engine with GLSL textures)

As soon as I press Play, the tracks created by NURBS path disappear. Am I missing some setting somewhere?

Here's the **[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gu0aui1z7esavjl/track.blend?dl=0)**

Answer (score 1):

I kinda figured out the problem. I had to select the Nurbs Path and then click on
Object --> Apply --> Make Duplicates Real in the bottom menu of 3D view.